# Is it possible to scale a HTML web page viewport to a large screen?

Tags: html, css

I am using the meta viewport to make Web pages adapt to mobile devices with the usual tags like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

However many of my site users have large screens. The used viewport width is 1025px, so with larger screens, say width larger than 1920px, the users would prefer to make better use of the left and right space outside the main contain that is always empty.

Is there way to make the zoom scale of the page adapt to the viewport width when it is higher than 1025px?

I suspect that some combination of meta viewport tag attributes and some media queries it may be possible but I could not find anything to make it responsive to large screens, only to smaller screens.

Comment: I would avoid zooming/scaling content considering the effect it would have on site assets (imagery, etc...) and [positioning](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/); rather just create a responsive design and stick to [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Media-queries alone should take care of this. Are you trying to just zoom in or out the whole website without writing css for each break-point? I don't get it...

Comment: @miro sorry, I was not clear. I will write the necessary CSS if that is the way to go. I am just not familiar with the necessary syntax that would make zoom level adapt to the screen width. For small screens I just hide less important elements so the main elements can fit well. But I never did any CSS or meta viewport tags for adjusting the zoom scale. It's probably simpler than I can imagine. I am just not familiar with it.

Comment: @Justinw good point. Maybe I should use SVG for icons or limit the zoom scale to something not too high like 150% when the the viewport width is larger than 1025px. I am not finding any good resources on documenting all the options of meta viewport tag. That is why I asked here.

Comment: You don't touch the zoom. You use the break-points to write new CSS to resize each element. For example the site width or the body font-size. Can you provide link to site?

Comment: I know how to set the zoom scale to specific values when the width is higher than a given pixel width, but I was hoping for a solution that would increase the zoom scale gradually as the viewport width increases.

Comment: @miro just increasing the font-size could be an idea. Here is the URL: http://www.phpclasses.org/ the responsive CSS is in responsive.css .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another media-query to handle high resolutions

### [Demo for >1280px](http://jsbin.com/nanaxecebe/edit?css,output)

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1280px) {

#Container {
    width: 95%;
}

#PageContent {
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 100%
}


#PageInfo {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.InfoContent{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.c640{
  width:20%;
}

.c640 .box{
  width:100%;
}

#navigation{
  width:auto;
}

.box{
  float:none;
}

}
```

It's not perfect but you can use this break-point add add more style and fix whatever doesn't look good on higher resolutions.

Comment: Thanks. It works well at least to adjust container sizes. By the way, if I just want to adjust font sizes, would I have to set them for all styles in all break points, or is there some CSS property to set the zoom level of font for text that would not affect images?

Comment: You can change the font-size globally using this `html *{font-size:105%;}`

Comment: Also, you can replace all of the above with `body {zoom: 1.2;}` I think that's what you were asking for originally but keep in mind that it's bad practice and may not work well in all browsers. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/huyonabugi/edit?css,output) - works on chrome but not FF

Comment: Yes, too bad it does not work on FF. I also tried the font-size trick on Chrome and it did not work well. I am not sure why. Any clues?